# Java - Unexpected result from splitting

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Why does

```
int a = 1234;
String b = a + "";
String[] c = b.split("");
```

Result in:

```
c[0] = ""
c[1] = "1"
c[2] = "2"
c[3] = "3"
c[4] = "4"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String.split` takes a regular expression String as an argument.  You have provided an empty regex, which matches the empty string.  Thus, you get one empty string match from the start of the string and then every character split by an empty string.  You should probably provide a valid regex.

---

Ordinarily there would be an empty string at the end of the split, but Java intentionally excludes this from the array resulting from `.split` with this one-argument usage.

```
$ php -r "var_dump(preg_split('//', 1234));"
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: you are right, but why the first character is "" instead of 1.

Comment: @lwinhtooko: To understand this, think about the fact that doing `",a,b".split(",")` similarly results in `["", "a", "b"]`.  It's nothing special about the empty string, it's just that any string you would split with the empty string as the delimiter would be considered to start with a delimiter, just like in the comma example.  The real confusing part is why isn't it considered to *end* with a delimiter too? :-)

Comment: *I'm actually not sure why there is no final empty string...but I would say it's not something you should depend on.*  I'm not exactly clear on why there's not either, but you should be able to rely on it.  From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): *Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.*

Comment: @Explosion: My curiosity keeps getting the better of me; this is something I didn't know about `split()`.  `split("")` is just an alias for `split("", 0)`. It turns out that specifying any negative value for the limit (the second argument) means "don't limit the number of results", and specifying `0` means "don't limit the number of results, and don't including trailing empty strings".  Very interesting.  So `split("", -1)` would be equivalent to the PHP code you've given.

Comment: Thank you Explosion Pills! Same for MarkPeters, this comment box explains it.

Comment: Seems like this behavior changed with (at least recent Oracle versions of) Java 8. `System.out.println("abc".split("").length);` prints `3` in Java 8, while it used to print `4` in Java 7.